# Is there a word for powerful people in politics?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for powerful people in politics? There has to be, I know the word "insider", but "insiders" aren't all that powerful, some are, but they are not the ones who make the decisions necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a single word that applies to politics *specifically*, but you could make use of [**magnate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magnate):

> : a person of rank, power, influence, or distinction often in a specified area
>   // a railroad *magnate*

Since it could be true of any field, a qualification is necessary:

> She was a *political* ***magnate***.

---

From Wikipedia's entry on [George Maitland Lloyd Davies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_M._Ll._Davies) (emphasis mine):

> Davies was born in Peel Road, Sefton Park, Liverpool, grandson on his maternal side of a noted Welsh preacher, John Jones, Talysarn; his family was wealthy - his cousin was David Davies of Llandinam, a Welsh industrial and *political* ***magnate***.

From ["5 Surprising Facts about the Patty Hearst Kidnapping Saga"](https://www.csmonitor.com/Books/2016/0802/5-surprising-facts-about-the-Patty-Hearst-kidnapping-saga) by Randy Dotinga (emphasis mine):

> Terrorists had kidnapped Patricia Hearst, the young granddaughter of newspaper and *political* ***magnate*** William Randolph Hearst, and no one knew what chaos would come next.

From ["The Percy Family, Marching with English History"](https://general-history.com/the-percy-family-marching-with-english-history/) by Dean Smith (emphasis mine):

> Henry, 4th Lord of Alnwick soon became Edward’s most important courtier (and *political* ***magnate***). In 1377 Henry Percy was Marshal of England, and then Earl of Northumberland.

Answer (score 2):

The commonest term I've heard is "movers and shakers."

Answer (score 0):

**"Powerful politicians"** and **"abusive politicians"** (where it can be implying some considerable to significant degree power that can be abused). In **benefits / qualities** it is pretty **concise** (short) and also **associativity descriptive** and **simple for common understanding**. Because of those benefits it can be **relatively better term** than both 2-words alternative/option terms for this and also even some, I'm not sure if they are existing, 1-word option terms for the meaning because it's still pretty short and okay (as opposed to if it would be 3/4/more words) and also have mentioned other benefits

Answer (score 0):

"Statesman/Stateswoman".  This doesn't necessarily mean powerful, but it does imply it.